# Joomla 3.2 get Itemid for component view

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a menu link that links to a certain page on my component, entering this page will have the correct Itemid, the problem is that (I will give the same example as the joomla webiste) this view displays a list of puppies, but when I enter detailed view of a puppie I loose the Itemid.

I have a specific Itemid, that I want to assign to this detailed view, the menu is already created and assigned to the view with an XML file, now what I need is the best way to assign the Itemid to the links on the listing view...

This is the closest thing Joomla Docs seems to have http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, you can force an Itemid on the onbeforeread on the controller

```
function onAfterRoute() {
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$jinput->set('option', 'com_helloworld');
$jinput->set('view', 'helloview');
$jinput->set('Itemid', '200');
```

}